# Landscape screenshot returns portrait mode screen

Tags: ios, opengl-es, avcapturesession, vuforia

I'm taking openGL screenshot , if camera at portrait mode then take the snapshot it returns portrait mode. But if i rotate the camera into landscape mode from portrait mode then take screenshot it returns portrait mode screenshot only. But my camera view is showing live stream full mode and screenshot saving 1024X768.

ImageTargetsEAGLView.mm:

```
- (BOOL)presentFramebuffer

{

  if (_takePhotoFlag1)

{

   [self glToUIImage1];

     UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum([self glToUIImage1], nil, nil, nil);

      NSLog(@"Screenshot size: %d, %d", (int)[[self glToUIImage1] size].width, (int)[[self glToUIImage1] size].height);

 _takePhotoFlag1 = NO;

   }     

        // setFramebuffer must have been called before presentFramebuffer, therefore

    // we know the context is valid and has been set for this (render) thread



    // Bind the colour render buffer and present it

    glBindRenderbuffer(GL_RENDERBUFFER, colorRenderbuffer);



    return [context presentRenderbuffer:GL_RENDERBUFFER];

}





- (UIImage*) glToUIImage1

{ 

UIImage *outputImage = nil;



    UIInterfaceOrientation orientation = [UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarOrientation;

        if (UIInterfaceOrientationIsLandscape(orientation))

        {

            NSLog(@"landscape screen");

            CGRect screenBounds = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];

   //  CGFloat scale = [[UIScreen mainScreen] scale];

            // CGRect s = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320.0f * scale, 480.0f * scale);

              CGRect  s = CGRectMake(0, 0, 1024 , 768);

             uint8_t *buffer = (uint8_t *) malloc(s.size.width * s.size.height * 4);

              glReadPixels(0, 0, s.size.width, s.size.height, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, buffer);

            CGDataProviderRef ref = CGDataProviderCreateWithData(NULL, buffer, s.size.width * s.size.height * 4, NULL);

             CGImageRef iref = CGImageCreate(s.size.width, s.size.height, 8, 32, s.size.width * 4, CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB(), kCGBitmapByteOrderDefault, ref, NULL, true, kCGRenderingIntentDefault);



            size_t width = CGImageGetWidth(iref);

            size_t height = CGImageGetHeight(iref);

            size_t length = width * height * 4;

            uint32_t *pixels = (uint32_t *)malloc(length);

            CGContextRef context1 = CGBitmapContextCreate(pixels, width, height, 8, width * 4,

                                                          CGImageGetColorSpace(iref), kCGImageAlphaNoneSkipFirst | kCGBitmapByteOrder32Big);



            CGAffineTransform transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity;

            transform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(0.0f, height);

            transform = CGAffineTransformScale(transform, 1.0, -1.0);

            CGContextConcatCTM(context1, transform);

            CGContextDrawImage(context1, CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, width, height), iref);

            CGImageRef outputRef = CGBitmapContextCreateImage(context1);

               outputImage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage: outputRef];

          CGDataProviderRelease(ref);

            CGImageRelease(iref);

            CGContextRelease(context1);

            CGImageRelease(outputRef);

            free(pixels);

            free(buffer);



        }else{



         NSLog(@"portrait screen");



        //    CGFloat scale = [[UIScreen mainScreen] scale];

            // CGRect s = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320.0f * scale, 480.0f * scale);



            CGRect  s = CGRectMake(0, 0, 768, 1024);



            uint8_t *buffer = (uint8_t *) malloc(s.size.width * s.size.height * 4);



            glReadPixels(0, 0, s.size.width, s.size.height, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, buffer);



            CGDataProviderRef ref = CGDataProviderCreateWithData(NULL, buffer, s.size.width * s.size.height * 4, NULL);





            CGImageRef iref = CGImageCreate(s.size.width, s.size.height, 8, 32, s.size.width * 4, CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB(), kCGBitmapByteOrderDefault, ref, NULL, true, kCGRenderingIntentDefault);



            size_t width = CGImageGetWidth(iref);

            size_t height = CGImageGetHeight(iref);

            size_t length = width * height * 4;

            uint32_t *pixels = (uint32_t *)malloc(length);







            CGContextRef context1 = CGBitmapContextCreate(pixels, width, height, 8, width * 4,

                                                          CGImageGetColorSpace(iref), kCGImageAlphaNoneSkipFirst | kCGBitmapByteOrder32Big);



            CGAffineTransform transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity;

            transform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(0.0f, height);

            transform = CGAffineTransformScale(transform, 1.0, -1.0);

            CGContextConcatCTM(context1, transform);

            CGContextDrawImage(context1, CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, width, height), iref);

            CGImageRef outputRef = CGBitmapContextCreateImage(context1);





            outputImage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage: outputRef];



            CGDataProviderRelease(ref);

            CGImageRelease(iref);

            CGContextRelease(context1);

            CGImageRelease(outputRef);

            free(pixels);

            free(buffer);





        }





        return outputImage;



    }



}
```

Comment: a) how are you viewing the SS and b) does the landscape SS look like a regular portrait SS or like you took a landscape SS and rotated it onto it's side?

Comment: please check this screenshot i'm getting black while saving https://developer.vuforia.com/sites/default/files/landscape_Screen.JPG

Comment: The problem is if i'm open the app in portrait mode and take screenshot it works. If i open the app in landscape mode then take screenshot it works. But if i rotate from portrait to landscape then take screenshot it shows black

Answer (score 0):

I don't have the same issue with your code you do, but I do get artifacting, etc. I would suggest using the method found here: http://www.unagames.com/blog/daniele/2011/10/opengl-es-screenshots-ios 
It worked perfectly for me as a drop-in replacement for yours (if you are using a GLKViewController then you just give it self.view as the eaglview) and it actually is pulling the correct size for the SS from the OpenGL ES context so you know it's always correct^^

Comment: In link, the code taking ss in portrait mode. But if i'm in landscape still that code taking portrait ss only. How can i change the code for landscape?